# Can you set "Enable delete protection" to VM instances in bulk in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I can't find the answer to this anywhere, but can you set "Enable delete protection" to VM instances in bulk in Google Cloud? Perhaps there is a CLI or plugin to do this? I can see that you can apply this to existing and for newly created instances, but we have hundreds of instances that will take time to do.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

It is possible via CLI with a loop. An example for machines in the same zone would be:

```
for vm in gcloud compute instances list --format="csv('NAME')"; do 
    gcloud compute instances update $vm --zone=[ZONE] --deletion-protection; 
done
```

You can easily extend it to work for multiple zones by getting `NAME` and `ZONE` from `compute instances list`

Comment: Thank you - will give that a go